# AttributeError: module 'git' has no attribute 'Repo' - working on local machine but not on remote server

Tags: python, gitpython

I've read through other solutions on here for general module x has no attribute y to no avail. What's catching me here is that this works fine on my local machine. When I transfer it over to a remote machine (with the same version of gitpython, python3 and pip installed) it throws the above error.

Code is pretty simple

```
import git
```

I have also tried

```
from git import Repo
```

and

```
from git import *
```

and further down:

```
repo = git.Repo("path/to/repo")
```

Comment: On the machine where it's not working, is it possible you have a file called `git.py` shadowing the real git package? Print `git.__file__` after your `import git` and it should tell you where it found the package. Make sure it's where you'd expect it.

Comment: Sorry I might be misunderstanding something in your suggestion here, but when I attempt to print git.__file__ it tells me git doesn't have an attribute '__file__'

Comment: Everything you import in Python should have a `__file__` attribute (that's underscore, underscore, "file", underscore, underscore) indicating where it got loaded from on the file system. I'm not sure what can be going on if that's not the case!